# Concatenate string in LESS variable?

Tags: css, less

This is my LESS code.

```
.borderalignment(@borderalignmentposition) {
    -moz-border-radius-bottom~@{borderalignmentposition}: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-top~@{borderalignmentposition}: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-~@{borderalignmentposition}-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-~@{borderalignmentposition}-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-~@{borderalignmentposition}-radius: 0;
}
```

I am trying to call the code like this.

```
.borderalignment(left);
```

Now I am getting an error that expected '}' but got 'm' This is working in an online compiler, but now in my app. My LESS version is 2.7.

Comment: What line does it say the "expected '}'" is on? I wonder if the problem isn't with the code you have shown here but somewhere else in the file.

Comment: 1. What's that `~` is doing there? 2. Discover autoprefixer and never write such ancient vendor prefixing mixins anymore.